The differences between the Box topology and the disjoint union topology
Let $X_1=\mathbb R^{ \mathbb N}$ and $\tau_1$ be the Box topology on $X_1$
Let $X_2=\bigsqcup_{i \in \Lambda} \mathbb R$ and $\tau_2$ be the Disjoint union topology on $X_2$.
Let $X_3=\mathbb R \times \Lambda$ and $\tau_3$ be the Product topology
$\Lambda$ is $\mathbb N$ equipped with the discrete topology.
Are any two of $\langle X_1,\tau_1 \rangle, \langle X_2,\tau_2 \rangle, \langle X_3,\tau_3 \rangle$ homeomorphic (i.e., do the above claims denote three different ways to describe the same topological space)?
Thanks
Editing remark: $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which implies that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N} = \prod_{\alpha \in \mathbb N} \mathbb{R}$

$X_2$ and $X_3$ are homeomorphic, that much is fine. $X_1$ and the other two don’t even have the same cardinality, so they are not homeomorphic.

(I mean, even in your finite example, there’s already no natural bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R} \sqcup \mathbb{R}$.)

Does $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ denote the product $\prod_{\alpha \in \mathbb R} \mathbb R$?

What is $\Lambda$?

@Smiley1000 It’s defined in the fourth line of the question.

Perhaps this question could be made more meaningful by adding your proof idea and then trying to find the flaw in the proof that $X_1 \cong X_2$.

Thank you @DavidGao, I have edited the first line. Your remark is, of course, correct

Use \langle and \rangle instead of < and > to get better size and spacing for the ordered pairs. Compare $\langle X,\tau \rangle$ with $<X,\tau>$.

@user135172 $X_1$ is still not homeomorphic to $X_2$ (though they are, of course, in bijection now). One way to see this is that $X_1$ is $\sigma$-compact while $X_2$ is not.

Thank you, @DavidGao, edited again

I think you made an error for $X_1$ while editing.

@user135172 … why are you trying all these different things for seemingly no reason at all? Anyway, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are still homeomorphic. And, assuming you meant $X_1 = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, it is still not homeomorphic to either $X_2$ or $X_3$. This time it’s because $X_2$ and $X_3$ are $\sigma$-compact while $X_1$ is not.

$X_1 = \mathbb N$?

Corrected, Thank you.  The reason to my question, I am finding this book (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/11601562) very interesting. However, I think some of the "disasters" described there would occur also using ZFC system with Box (instead of Product) topology. However, to do that, I should improve my understanding of the Box Topology. So I was trying to generate a few examples for myself..

@user135172 I’d say you’re focusing on the wrong examples then. There’s never much reason $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$ should be related, and this is true whether you use box or product topologies. In general, box topologies on infinite products are nearly always badly behaved, so trying to find spaces homeomorphic to them among “nice” spaces is unlikely to succeed. (One exception might be that the box topology on a product of discrete spaces is actually the discrete topology on the product, which is nicer than the product topology in a sense.)

In case you are still interested in a rigorous proof of $X_1\not\simeq X_2 \simeq X_3$, here it is :)
$X_2$ is homeomorphic to $X_3$
First, identify every element in $X_2$ as a pair $(x,i) \in \mathbb{R} \times \Lambda$, where $i$ indicates the index of the version of $\mathbb{R}$ that $x$ belongs to. With this notation, it is clear that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are in bijection, so the only thing left to prove is that $\tau_2 = \tau_3$.
Let $O \in \tau_3$ and $\{\varphi_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the set of functions $\varphi_j : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X_2$ defined by $\varphi_j(x) = (x,j)$. To prove that $O \in \tau_2$, it is enough to show that $\varphi_j^{-1}(O)$ is open for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. To do this, note that if $x \in \varphi_j^{-1}(O)$, then $(x,j) \in O$. Since the product of topology bases is a basis for the product topology (for finite products), there is an open set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x,j) \in B \times \{j\} \subset O$. It follows that $x \in B \subset \varphi_j^{-1}(O)$. Since this holds for arbitrary $x,j$, it follows that $\varphi_j^{-1}(O)$ is open for all $j$, and thus $O \in \tau_2$.
Now let $O \in \tau_2$, meaning that $\varphi_j^{-1}(O) = O_j$ is open for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Observe that if $(x,j) \in O$, then $(x,j) \in O_j \times \{j\} \subset O$. Since $O_j \times \{j\}\in\tau_3$, it follows that $O \in \tau_3$.
$X_1$ is not homeomorphic to $X_3$
To prove that $X_1 \not\simeq X_3$, we will show that $X_1$ is not separable, while $X_3$ is.
By contradiction, assume that $X = \{x^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X_1$ is a dense subset of $X_1$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, pick an open set $O_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n^n \notin O_n$. Observe that the set $O = O_1\times O_2\times\dots$ is open in the box topology. If $x^j \in O$, then $x_j^j \in O_j$, which is a contradiction. It follows that $O \cap X = \emptyset$, so $X$ is not dense, and $X_1$ is not separable.
To see that $X_3$ is separable, consider $D = \mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{N}$, and let $O \subset X_3$ be a non-empty set with $(x,j) \in O$. Since $O$ is open, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) \times \{j\} \subset O$. Finally, observe that
$$\emptyset \neq ((x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) \cap \mathbb{Q}) \times \{j\} \subset O \cap D.$$
It follows that $D$ is both dense and countable, and therefore $X_3$ is separable.

$X_2$ and $X_3$ are both homeomorphic to a countable number of disjoint real lines (for example, the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the $y$ coordinate is an integer).
$X_1$ is much higher-dimensional than the other (1-dimensional) spaces, thus is not homeomorphic to the other two. For a concrete example why, $X_1$ has open sets homeomorphic to $(0,1)^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, while the other two have open sets homeomorphic to the open interval but not any of its higher-dimensional analogues.
